# Android GPS Speed

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a question about android.location.Location.getSpeed().
I have implemented my LocationListener and specified its provider to use GPS. This way getSpeed() is always 0.0. I have read about this, no problem. Now, when I set up Criteria and specify

```
criteria.setSpeedRequired( true );
```

and further down

```
String bestProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true );
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( bestProvider, mIntervaltime, mDistance, locationListener );
```

bestProvider is again the GPS provider, but I receive speed values. Why's that? What's the difference between LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and mLocationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true ); when both reveal that they use the GPS provider by checking:

```
Log.i( TAG, "  Provider: " + location.getProvider() );
```

Comment: silly android design. evry GPS chip provides speed data. the only thing when that would makes sense is when the user of the phone could prohibit the device to record speed values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but you have to be moving for the GPS to report a speed value greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a bit of an overhead to recording and processing the speed. And since you dont always need to know the speed, it makes sense to make the enabling optional, even if the provider stays the same.